# MongoDB does not yield a covered query even after projecting only indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is the MongoDB driver I'm using ( Maven dependency ):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've made two indexes for my collection:

```
    this.collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending(
                "author",
                "created_utc",
                "subreddit"
            ));
    this.collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending(
                "created_utc"
            ));
```

I ran `db.collection.getIndexes()` and they're actually there.

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "reddit.dump"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "created_utc" : 1
        },
        "name" : "created_utc_1",
        "ns" : "reddit.dump"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "author" : 1,
            "created_utc" : 1,
            "subreddit" : 1
        },
        "name" : "author_1_created_utc_1_subreddit_1",
        "ns" : "reddit.dump"
    }
]
```

And then I made this query:

```
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = this.collection
            .find(and(
                      gte("created_utc", this.lowerBound),
                      lt("created_utc", this.upperBound)))
            .projection(fields(include("author", "created_utc", "subreddit"), 
                        exclude("_id"))).iterator();
```

`this.lowerBound` and `this.upperBound` are integers, and `this.upperBound > this.lowerBound`.

For some unknown reason, MongoDB doesn't seem to be accepting this as a covered query.

When I run the equivalent command directly on mongo and ask for an explanation:

```
db.dump.find(
{created_utc: {$gt: 1543622399, $lt: 1543622401 }}, 
{author: 1, created_utc: 1, subreddit: 1, _id: 0})
.explain("executionStats")
```

I get a `IXSCAN` that descends from a `FETCH` and `totalDocsExamined` is not zero. So it's not a covered query. Here's the full output of the explanation:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "reddit.dump",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "created_utc" : {
                        "$lt" : 1543622401
                    }
                },
                {
                    "created_utc" : {
                        "$gt" : 1543622399
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "transformBy" : {
                "author" : 1,
                "created_utc" : 1,
                "subreddit" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "created_utc" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "created_utc_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "created_utc" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "created_utc" : [
                            "(1543622399.0, 1543622401.0)"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 44,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 44,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 44,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "nReturned" : 44,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 45,
            "advanced" : 44,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "transformBy" : {
                "author" : 1,
                "created_utc" : 1,
                "subreddit" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "nReturned" : 44,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 45,
                "advanced" : 44,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 44,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 44,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 45,
                    "advanced" : 44,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 0,
                    "restoreState" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "created_utc" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "created_utc_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "created_utc" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "created_utc" : [
                            "(1543622399.0, 1543622401.0)"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 44,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "user-System-Product-Name",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.3",
        "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

How to make a covered query that will achieve the same results?

Here's how a document on my collection looks like:

```
{
    "archived": false,
    "author": "HRNNNGH",
    "author_created_utc": 1533311589,
    "author_flair_background_color": null,
    "author_flair_css_class": null,
    "author_flair_richtext": [],
    "author_flair_template_id": null,
    "author_flair_text": null,
    "author_flair_text_color": null,
    "author_flair_type": "text",
    "author_fullname": "t2_1kcmg9n3",
    "author_patreon_flair": false,
    "body": "I LOVE THIS",
    "can_gild": true,
    "can_mod_post": false,
    "collapsed": false,
    "collapsed_reason": null,
    "controversiality": 0,
    "created_utc": 1543622400,
    "distinguished": null,
    "edited": false,
    "gilded": 0,
    "gildings": {
        "gid_1": 0,
        "gid_2": 0,
        "gid_3": 0
    },
    "id": "eatm38p",
    "is_submitter": false,
    "link_id": "t3_a1vhzf",
    "no_follow": false,
    "parent_id": "t3_a1vhzf",
    "permalink": "/r/ACPocketCamp/comments/a1vhzf/welcome_to_my_hair_salon/eatm38p/",
    "removal_reason": null,
    "retrieved_on": 1546258274,
    "score": 4,
    "send_replies": true,
    "stickied": false,
    "subreddit": "ACPocketCamp",
    "subreddit_id": "t5_3pg1s",
    "subreddit_name_prefixed": "r/ACPocketCamp",
    "subreddit_type": "public"
}
```

And here's what I want to achieve with a covered query:

```
{ "author" : "MyPhantomAccount", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "ireland" }
{ "author" : "ardentArcane", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "heroesofthestorm" }
{ "author" : "bbrownabbb", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "nonononoyes" }
{ "author" : "DANKNESSLEVEL-69", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "memes" }
{ "author" : "HRNNNGH", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "ACPocketCamp" }
{ "author" : "DomIstKrieg", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "AskReddit" }
{ "author" : "befooks", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "northernlion" }
{ "author" : "meekosmom", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "raisedbynarcissists" }
{ "author" : "[deleted]", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "wallstreetbets" }
{ "author" : "Red580", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "ForwardsFromKlandma" }
{ "author" : "rauland", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "melbourne" }
{ "author" : "Mr-Morrison94", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "FortNiteBR" }
{ "author" : "huskiesofinternets", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "aww" }
{ "author" : "AnimaCorpusLucra", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "wallstreetbets" }
{ "author" : "Shadow14l", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "financialindependence" }
{ "author" : "potrap", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "popheads" }
{ "author" : "FireandBloodandStuff", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "dankmemes" }
{ "author" : "XChihiro", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "AskReddit" }
{ "author" : "bjacks12", "created_utc" : 1543622400, "subreddit" : "latterdaysaints" }
```

Comment: Does the explain say it's using the 3-field index or the created_utc-only index?

Comment: I've added the full output of the explain to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, mongodb won't consider your 3-field index for this query because it doesn't have the "author" to reduce the index search space (even if you're getting from all authors anyway). Even when given a [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) to use the 3-field index, it still doesn't produce a covered query (I couldn't tell you why).

To get a covered query, you'll need to re-create your 3-field index with `created_utc` listed first.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, the whole point of covered queries is to use a single index for lookup AND results; if these are not the same, you've lost the main benefit already.

Comment: "To get a covered query, you'll need to re-create your 3-field index with created_utc listed first. " This worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you [read carefully](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-queries),

> A covered query is a query that can be satisfied entirely using an
>   index and does not have to examine any documents. An index covers a
>   query when both of the following apply:
>
> - all the fields in the query are part of an index, and
> - all the fields returned in the results are in the same index.

It is not explicitly stated, but careful reading of this clearly explains that it meant *a single* index satisfying both query and projection.